# /etc/network/interfaces - multiple gateways 3 NICs

Tags: networking, network-interface, ip, gateway

Good Evening,

Is this a correct network configuration? All of the routing takes place on my switches and firewall. Each server is able to ping the other on each subnet. Is there an issue with using multiple gateways on the same NIC? New to networking. Thank you!

What's the best way to handle multiple gateways?

Here is my etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eno1 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 192.168.48.10
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.48.1
        bridge_ports eno1
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0

iface enp8s0f0 inet manual

iface enp8s0f1 inet manual

auto eno2
iface eno2 inet static
        address 192.168.49.10
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.49.1

auto enp10s0f0
iface enp10s0f0 inet static
        address 192.168.50.10
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.50.1

auto enp10s0f1
iface enp10s0f1 inet static
        address 192.168.51.10
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.51.1
```

updated 09/11

That configuration above is giving me an error message on boot. The servers are able to ping each other and connect through each separate IP. There are 3 NICs on the servers.

```
root@vmhost02:~# systemctl status networking.service
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-09-10 19:47:21 EDT; 24h ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 933 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 933 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 10 19:47:18 vmhost02 ifup[933]: Waiting for vmbr0 to get ready (MAXWAIT is 2 seconds).
Sep 10 19:47:18 vmhost02 ifup[933]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Sep 10 19:47:18 vmhost02 ifup[933]: ifup: failed to bring up eno2
Sep 10 19:47:20 vmhost02 ifup[933]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Sep 10 19:47:20 vmhost02 ifup[933]: ifup: failed to bring up enp10s0f0
Sep 10 19:47:21 vmhost02 ifup[933]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Sep 10 19:47:21 vmhost02 ifup[933]: ifup: failed to bring up enp10s0f1
Sep 10 19:47:21 vmhost02 systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=
Sep 10 19:47:21 vmhost02 systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 10 19:47:21 vmhost02 systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
```

I have hardware switches and a firewall taking care of the VLAN between the 3 servers.

Would configuring linux VLAN within my network configuration file solve the failed start?

I added the tags to my configuration file, but I'm unfamiliar with how to do it or if it will solve my problem. I'm also unfamiliar with post-up and policy routing.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Answer (score 1):

This link will describe how to do "load balancing" beetween this two gateways...

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html

It is important for you to read it carefully specially on the start, as the author explain what will gonna be each variable in the configuration.

Comment: I have 3 nodes that all need 3 separate private networks. corosync, and ceph on proxmox (ceph requires 2). Would each one of my interfaces for each node be Provider, 1, 2, 3. I would just need to configure them in each direction?